# TypeError: v.setActiveFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating my project in ReactJS. In this projects, there is the page into I should make a textarea. This page is divided in two part, the sidebar, where you see all the files of the current workspace, and the editor, an html textarea. When I click a button, I would like that the current file changes. So, I created a context to pass to the child element. Here is the code of the Parent component, we can call it:

```
import '../styles/style.css';
import Editor from './Editor'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import React,  {useState} from 'react';

const WContext = React.createContext();

const EditPage = () => {
    const {activeFile, setActiveFile} = useState('Empty');


    return <>
        <WContext.Provider value={{activeFile, setActiveFile}}>
        <h1 className="edittitle">Edit Page</h1>
        <div className="edit">
            <Sidebar />
            <Editor />
        </div>
        </WContext.Provider>
    </>
}

export default EditPage;
export {WContext};
```

Then, there is the sidebar code:

```
import {useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {WContext} from './EditPage';
import axios from 'axios';

const Sidebar = () => {
    const v = useContext(WContext);
    const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //request to server
    }, [])

    return <>
        <div className="sidebar">
            <h3>Files of workspace</h3>
            <div className="sidesaparator"></div>
            {
                file.map(f=>{
                    return <button key={f._id} onClick={() => v.setActiveFile(f)} style={{'padding':"10px"}}>
                        {f.name + "." + f.extension}</button>
                })
            }
        </div>
    </>
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Finally, the editor code:

```
import sun from '../images/sun.png';
import moon from '../images/moon.png';
import {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {WContext} from './EditPage';

const Editor = () => {
    const v = useContext(WContext);
    const [text, setText] = useState('//Your code');

    const handleChanges = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value); 
        setLine(countLine); 
    }

    return <>
        <form className="editor">
            <div className="opened">  {v.activeFile}  </div>
            
            <textarea name="code" value={text} className="editorText" onChange={handleChanges} spellCheck="false" 
            id = {bg}></textarea>
            
        </form>
    </>
}

export default Editor;
```

In this last file, the div with className "opened" should have as text the value of activeFile, but it is an empty string. On the other hand, in the previus file, when I click in one file, it should become the active one, but the error in the question title appears. I would like to know where I'm mistaking, and how to fix it. Thank you so much

Comment: your context will not be exported until you have a default export in your page.

Comment: The fact is that is not the main page, so I need to export both

Comment: then use export {WContext,EditPage}

Comment: No, it didn't worked

Comment: have u used context provider to wrap your related components? i can's see it

Comment: Yes I did. If you look in the import, you can see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this can be fixed by switching from brakets to square parentesis the useState declaration